# USB detection not working correctly

Tags: usb, yocto

I have a custom yocto image I have built for a karo module. Running 5.7.1 Kernel.

When I insert a usb drive, it does not show up in the output of "lsblk" as I would expect it to. It does show up in "lsusb", so I know the drive is detected by the system, but something is off maybe in how the kernel is processing it?

I have many of the debug options enabled in the kernel, so here is that output when the drive is inserted

```
root@txmp-1530:~# [  451.851889] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-platform
[  452.004112] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[  452.011016] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  452.018427] usb 1-1.1: Product: Flash Disk
[  452.022432] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: USB
[  452.026288] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: SCY0000000271192
[  452.031340] device: '1-1.1': device_add
[  452.035347] bus: 'usb': add device 1-1.1
[  452.039134] PM: Adding info for usb:1-1.1
[  452.045798] bus: 'usb': driver_probe_device: matched device 1-1.1 with driver usb
[  452.051941] bus: 'usb': really_probe: probing driver usb with device 1-1.1
[  452.058854] usb 1-1.1: no default pinctrl state
[  452.063898] device: '1-1.1:1.0': device_add
[  452.067446] bus: 'usb': add device 1-1.1:1.0
[  452.071695] PM: Adding info for usb:1-1.1:1.0
[  452.077418] bus: 'usb': driver_probe_device: matched device 1-1.1:1.0 with driver uas
[  452.084011] bus: 'usb': really_probe: probing driver uas with device 1-1.1:1.0
[  452.091073] uas 1-1.1:1.0: no default pinctrl state
[  452.095994] uas: probe of 1-1.1:1.0 rejects match -19
[  452.101346] bus: 'usb': driver_probe_device: matched device 1-1.1:1.0 with driver usb-storage
[  452.109502] bus: 'usb': really_probe: probing driver usb-storage with device 1-1.1:1.0
[  452.117436] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: no default pinctrl state
[  452.122991] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  452.129639] Vendor: 0x090c, Product: 0x1000, Revision: 0x1100
[  452.134956] Interface Subclass: 0x06, Protocol: 0x50
[  452.139840] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 090c pid 1000: 400
[  452.146734] Transport: Bulk
[  452.149470] Protocol: Transparent SCSI
[  452.153509] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
[  452.157617] device: 'host0': device_add
[  452.161408] bus: 'scsi': add device host0
[  452.161955] *** thread sleeping
[  452.165488] PM: Adding info for scsi:host0
[  452.173070] device: 'host0': device_add
[  452.176543] PM: Adding info for No Bus:host0
[  452.181033] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[  452.188048] driver: 'usb-storage': driver_bound: bound to device '1-1.1:1.0'
[  452.195481] bus: 'usb': really_probe: bound device 1-1.1:1.0 to driver usb-storage
[  452.202627] device: 'ep_81': device_add
[  452.206478] PM: Adding info for No Bus:ep_81
[  452.210643] device: 'ep_02': device_add
[  452.214594] PM: Adding info for No Bus:ep_02
[  452.218722] driver: 'usb': driver_bound: bound to device '1-1.1'
[  452.225409] bus: 'usb': really_probe: bound device 1-1.1 to driver usb
[  452.231297] device: 'ep_00': device_add
[  452.235675] PM: Adding info for No Bus:ep_00
[  453.191885] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: starting scan
[  453.195048] rq=fe rqtype=a1 value=0000 index=00 len=1
[  453.200261] GetMaxLUN command result is 1, data is 0
[  453.205490] *** thread awakened
[  453.208189] Command INQUIRY (6 bytes)
[  453.211899] bytes: 12 00 00 00 24 00
[  453.215377] Bulk Command S 0x43425355 T 0x1 L 36 F 128 Trg 0 LUN 0 CL 6
[  453.222067] xfer 31 bytes
[  453.224777] Status code 0; transferred 31/31
[  453.228833] -- transfer complete
[  453.232115] Bulk command transfer result=0
[  453.236143] xfer 36 bytes, 1 entries
[  453.338971] Status code 0; transferred 36/36
[  453.341769] -- transfer complete
[  453.345064] Bulk data transfer result 0x0
[  453.348992] Attempting to get CSW...
[  453.352595] xfer 13 bytes
[  453.355328] Status code 0; transferred 13/13
[  453.359404] -- transfer complete
[  453.362716] Bulk status result = 0
[  453.366024] Bulk Status S 0x53425355 T 0x1 R 0 Stat 0x0
[  453.371232] scsi cmd done, result=0x0
[  453.374939] *** thread sleeping
[  453.378159] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Flash Disk       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  453.386162] device: 'target0:0:0': device_add
[  453.390472] bus: 'scsi': add device target0:0:0
[  453.395040] PM: Adding info for scsi:target0:0:0
[  453.400124] device: '0:0:0:0': device_add
[  453.404002] bus: 'scsi': add device 0:0:0:0
[  453.407762] PM: Adding info for scsi:0:0:0:0
[  453.412525] device: '0:0:0:0': device_add
[  453.416281] PM: Adding info for No Bus:0:0:0:0
[  453.421030] device: '0:0:0:0': device_add
[  453.424821] PM: Adding info for No Bus:0:0:0:0
[  453.430287] *** thread awakened
[  453.432560] Bad LUN (0:1)
[  453.434572] scsi cmd done, result=0x40000
[  453.438571] *** thread sleeping
[  453.438736] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: scan complete
```

Drive is left in place, and there are these two command outputs.

```
root@txmp-1530:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 125b:0158  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 125b:0159  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@txmp-1530:~# 
root@txmp-1530:~# 
root@txmp-1530:~# 
root@txmp-1530:~# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0  3.5G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    2M  0 part 
|-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   64M  0 part 
|-mmcblk0p3  179:3    0  373M  0 part /
|-mmcblk0p4  179:4    0  373M  0 part 
`-mmcblk0p5  179:5    0  2.8G  0 part /opt/videx
mmcblk0boot0 179:16   0    2M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:32   0    2M  1 disk
```

Then I remove the device, and get this output.

```
root@txmp-1530:~# [  542.214305] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  542.218038] device: 'ep_81': device_unregister
[  542.222600] PM: Removing info for No Bus:ep_81
[  542.226870] device: 'ep_02': device_unregister
[  542.231375] PM: Removing info for No Bus:ep_02
[  542.235879] bus: 'usb': remove device 1-1.1:1.0
[  542.240270] device: '0:0:0:0': device_unregister
[  542.245121] PM: Removing info for No Bus:0:0:0:0
[  542.252005] device: '0:0:0:0': device_create_release
[  542.255531] device: '0:0:0:0': device_unregister
[  542.260516] PM: Removing info for No Bus:0:0:0:0
[  542.266061] bus: 'scsi': remove device 0:0:0:0
[  542.269352] PM: Removing info for scsi:0:0:0:0
[  542.274491] bus: 'scsi': remove device target0:0:0
[  542.278569] PM: Removing info for scsi:target0:0:0
[  542.283727] device: 'host0': device_unregister
[  542.287905] PM: Removing info for No Bus:host0
[  542.292759] bus: 'scsi': remove device host0
[  542.296442] PM: Removing info for scsi:host0
[  542.300931] -- sending exit command to thread
[  542.305293] *** thread awakened
[  542.307980] -- exiting
[  542.342645] PM: Removing info for usb:1-1.1:1.0
[  542.346463] device: 'ep_00': device_unregister
[  542.350428] PM: Removing info for No Bus:ep_00
[  542.355071] bus: 'usb': remove device 1-1.1
[  542.359538] PM: Removing info for usb:1-1.1
```

And again, the two ls commands after removal for reference.

```
root@txmp-1530:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 125b:0158  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 125b:0159  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@txmp-1530:~# 
root@txmp-1530:~# 
root@txmp-1530:~# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0  3.5G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    2M  0 part 
|-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   64M  0 part 
|-mmcblk0p3  179:3    0  373M  0 part /
|-mmcblk0p4  179:4    0  373M  0 part 
`-mmcblk0p5  179:5    0  2.8G  0 part /opt/videx
mmcblk0boot0 179:16   0    2M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:32   0    2M  1 disk 
root@txmp-1530:~#
```

Any additional information I should include to help track this down let me know. Thank you